# Animate bootstrap columns

Tags: jquery, html, animation, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

Here's what I'd like to do:

#### Initial Display

```
---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|              .span12 #col1                |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                                           |
|                               [#button]   |
|                                           |
|                                           |
---------------------------------------------
```

Then when #button gets clicked, #col1 contents are animated sliding over to the right into a .span3 and #col2 .span9 animates in from the left to the right (from off screen):

#### After Button Click/Animation

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                                |              |
|                                |              |
|                                |              |
|              .span9  #col2     | .span3 #col1 |
|                                |              |
|                                |              |
|                                |              |
|                                | [#button]    |
|                                |              |
|                                |              |
-------------------------------------------------
```

And then the inverse could happen to get to the original state.

Thanks!

## THE QUESTION IS

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap grid system. Googling `Twitter Bootstrap column transtions animation` and variations didn't turn up anything. I'm not a jquery animation guru, so I thought I'd beseech the *kind* people on stack overflow.

The hope is that there's someone on here that may know more than me about this sort of thing would answer with some code that shows how it can be achieved. Sorry, I thought that was implied just by posting on the site.

## Here's what I've tried

http://jsfiddle.net/KdhAB/3/

Comment: For future readers of this question using **Bootstrap 4**, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979772/bootstrap-4-animate-column-width-change

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This could be done with CSS3 transitions, which would be consistent with the way Bootstrap JS plugins accomplish their animations.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="col2" class="span0"></div>
    <div id="col1" class="span12">
      <a id="trig" class="btn btn-inverse">Reflow Me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

### JS

```
$('#trig').on('click', function () {
  $('#col1').toggleClass('span12 span3');
  $('#col2').toggleClass('span0 span9');
});​
```

### CSS

```
.row div {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
    transition: width 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
}

.span0 {
    width: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/9F62B/)

### [JSFiddle (Fluid)](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/274NN/5/)

<sub>**Note**: The animation is a still a bit imprecise, but I figure that can all be worked out separately.  This answer provides the basic outline of how to go about it.</sub>

Comment: This would be great if it worked with fluid layout, which my project uses.

Comment: @RonnieOverby Change `.container` to `.contaner-fluid` and `.row` to `.row-fluid`.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov right.... my project is already using those classes and this merv's approach doesn't work with fluid layout. Change the classes in the jsfiddle and it breaks as well.

Comment: Big +1 to @Jordan for adding the Fluid JSFiddle!  Sorry I didn't get around to it myself.

Comment: Here's a slightly modified fixed layout demo without overriding the margins: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Hbrzv/1/

Comment: Not sure why, but I have to add `visibility: hidden;` to the `.row-fluid .span0` rule so that the contents aren't showed. The jsFiddle example doesn't behave that way.

Comment: Ah yes, here's a fiddle with content in the span0: http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/6/ without the `overflow:hidden` rule the content will break out of the container. If you just put the `overflow:hidden` rule on the span0, you will see the content break breifly while animating to span12. In my fiddle you will noticed that the `overflow:hidden` rule is applied to both divs

Comment: Do you have the same example in Bootstrap 3 ?

Comment: how to use this with col-md-*. I am setting the width of col-md-0 as 0%, even then the element is showing up in the HTML.

Comment: Both JSFiddle links are broken. Anyone have them?

Comment: @Chad hmm looks like JSFiddle changed the url for directly linking to a result page. I corrected the links on this post to point to the editing page, but these are old examples (BS 2.x).

Answer (score 2):

This one is built on top of the responsive fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/274NN/74/

It is type of an edit flow e.g. suppose you want to show a sliding menu on click of a button:

1) Slide left column out of the window
2) Bring menu sliding from the right

Menu width is given in %, you can change it as per your needs

Comment: In your fiddle, how would you make it so that the column on the left doesnt get pushed but rather, compressed, so you can still see the text on it?

Comment: Your fiddle 404s

Comment: ya it was posted long time back, i guess they removed it.