# Bootstrap - Sliding Columns in and out

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a kind of swooping, sliding switcher for a website.  This is the state when the page is loaded: (The section on the right is a div with `display:none;`)

```
FIG 1:
|---------------------------------| |-----------| |#|
|                                 | |           | |r|
|                                 | |           | |e|
|             #search             | |  #filters | |s|
|            .col-md-9            | | .col-md-3 | |u|
|                                 | |           | |l|
|                                 | |   [btn]   | |t|
|---------------------------------| |-----------| |s|
```

When you click the `[btn]`, the `#search` div is supposed to swoop/slide off to the left, and a `#results` div swoop/slides in from the right, resulting in the arrangement in Figure 2:

```
FIG 2:
|#| |-----------| |---------------------------------|
|s| |           | |                                 |
|e| |           | |                                 |
|a| |  #filters | |             #results            |
|r| | .col-md-3 | |            .col-md-9            |
|c| |           | |                                 |
|h| |   [btn]   | |                                 |
| | |-----------| |---------------------------------|
```

The `#search` div is no longer rendered (i.e. `display:none;`), and the `#results` div now is visible.

Clicking the `[btn]` again would swap it back to the original arrangement.

Trying to accomplish this with jquery's `.animate()` left it with jerkiness, as `#results` was rendering as if it wrapped around to the next line (for lack of better term) until it completed the transition.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520751/animate-bootstrap-columns) which worked for a "right-nav" sort of thing, but when I tried to apply it to my own method, it crushed the left section and pushed the middle and bottom section down far off the page, meaning that it's still "display"ing (see Figure 3).  I figured to counteract this, I would have to do some fiddling with negative margin-left and margin-right values, in addition to toggling the display value or something.

```
FIG 3:
|#|
|s|
|e|
|a|
|r|
|c|
|h|
| |
| |
| |

|-----------| |---------------------------------|
|           | |                                 |
|           | |                                 |
|  #filters | |             #results            |
| .col-md-3 | |            .col-md-9            |
|           | |                                 |
|   [btn]   | |                                 |
|-----------| |---------------------------------|
```

I've been stumped on this for a while, and would appreciate the help.

Comment: not quite sure if you can, but you could probably alter [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzTJ/86/) for your html or look at this [accordian design, using jquery's layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos.cfm)

Comment: You can it's pretty easy with the question you reference ... but what have you tried?

Comment: @jbutler483: Accordion is not exactly what I need. I need the whole div to not render on the page by the time I'm done.

Comment: @Danko: I clarified what I'm trying to do, and one of my failed attempts.