# How to move bootstrap columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I'm using bootstrap and I need to move columns.
My page is composed by 4 columns fullpage height (col-md-3); I'm using also Fullpage.js.
I would like that when the user scroll to the section contains the columns, the user don't see the columns but these appear from the right (out of screen) to the left and fill the page.

this is the column's code

```
<div class="section" id="section1" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
        <div id="slogan" style="width:100%; text-align:center">
            <img src="images/slogan.png" style="width:50%; min-width: 530px;" />
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%">
            <div id="aa" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; background-color:#FFF5E9;">
                <img src="images/aa.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <img src="images/bb.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <a class="hidden-xs scroll" href="../Home.html#secondPage" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:-40px; top:-35px;"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="cc" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; background-color:#e3d4c1;">
                <img src="images/cc.png" style="width:60%" />
                <img src="images/vv.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <a class="hidden-xs scroll" href="../Home.html#secondPage" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:-40px; top:-35px;"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="dd" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; background-color:#FFF5E9;">
                <img src="images/gg.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <img src="images/hh.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <a class="hidden-xs scroll" href="../Home.html#secondPage" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:-40px; top:-35px;"></a>
            </div>

            <div id="rr" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; text-align:center; background-color:#e3d4c1;">
                <img src="images/rr.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <img src="images/yy.png" style="width:60%;" />
                <a class="hidden-xs scroll" href="../Home.html#secondPage"     style="margin:0px; padding:0px; margin-left:-40px; top:-35px;"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now the columns are visible, but i would like that arrive from the right (out of screen).

Thanks!!

Comment: show us your codes ....

Comment: Are a talking about a carousel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an animation of your content for a specific section.

In that case you can use many plugins by just googling it.

I found one that can maybe satisfy you : http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/

The instructions are very simple. Let me know if you have any issue with this.

Otherwise you can also check already answered to similar question : [Animate bootstrap columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520751/animate-bootstrap-columns)