# Animating delay on bootstrap container classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap framework on my website, with the content wrapped in `class="container"`

This has certain break-points when the screen resizes, the cols, margins, etc change.

I wanted to put a delay on that break point but not sure how to go about it. So when the side margins change from one size to another, the content doesn't just jump to the new size, but animates into it.

Comment: how about using transitions?
something like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010939/how-to-make-bootstrap-responsive-divs-transition-when-their-width-property-disap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example of the CSS that you can use:

```
-webkit-transition:width 1000ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:width 1000ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition:width 1000ms ease-in-out;
transition:width 1000ms ease-in-out;
```

Basically what it does, is that when the property "width" changes specifies a transition effect with a slow start and end of 1 second.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdsjy3we/1/) with an example. You have to move your mouse hover the red DIV to see the effect.

[More information](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) about this CSS property.

Comment: I do get how the transition property works, The problem is that Bootstrap has all it's own back-end css/java that controls all that, not sure which properties I can override or add to that are already established

Comment: It's bootstrap code which is brought in from their side. It is just brought into my site through functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something similar to the following CSS to your container element:

```
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
```