# Angular2 animation with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-animation

I have a row divided in 3 columns with 2 buttons to hide the right and left panels :

```
 col-md-3      col-md-7      col-md-2
------------------------------------
|         |                  |     |
|   left  |   middle panel   |     | <= right panel
|  panel  |                  |     |
|         |                  |     |
|         |                  |     |
------------------------------------
<<<                              >>>
```

When I click on left button, I want my middle panel to take all the space left on the left :

```
            col-md-10       col-md-2
------------------------------------
|                            |     |
|      middle panel          |     | <= right panel
|                            |     |
|                            |     |
|                            |     |
------------------------------------
<<<                              >>>
```

And the same behavior on the right, when I click on the right button.
If I click on both, my middle panel should take all the space.

It works well when I just switch classes on my div (col-md-7 => col-md-12 for example).
Now I would like it to be animated, with a smooth transition. I tried following this response : [Animate bootstrap columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520751/animate-bootstrap-columns])
But I don't want to use JQuery. Is it possible with Angular2 animation ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this effect with the appropriate CSS styles and *ngIf / [ngClass] on the panels:

**CSS**

```
.middle-panel {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="left-panel col-md-3" *ngIf="(middleToggled == false)"></div>

<div class="middle-panel" [ngClass]="{ 'col-md-7' : (! middleToggled), 'col-md-10' : (middleToggled) }"></div>

<div class="right-panel col-md-2"></div>
```

Comment: I tried something similar but it does not work properly. When I click on the right button, it works well, but this is the only case.
When I click on the left button, the middle panel move the left and expand on its right.
When I click a second time on the right, my panel is displayed before the animation ends, and shows a little time on a second row, because the middle panel is still in 'col-md-9'