# bootstrap 4 animate column width change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have two columns like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am switching the classnames via angular to be  `col-8 offset-2` and `col-0` . `col-0` is `width:0;margin:0;padding:0`.

I am wondering how to animate both the width, and the positions of columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I have tried angular's inbuilt animate system which won't work because my div contains a router outlet, I have also tried styles but I cannot figure out how to make the widths and positions translate smoothly without wrapping onto a new line. I've tried auto-width columns which don't seem to work either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520751/animate-bootstrap-columns

Comment: I will when I've resolved it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox, CSS transition animations don't work unless you use set a numeric `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` on the columns.

```
.col-8 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.col-0 {
  width: 0; 
  flex-shrink: 1;
  transition: all 400ms ease;
}
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/4Un0Q8CvkQ

---

To animate the grid columns as they change the media query breakpoints (instead of toggle classes via jQuery), you can simply use a CSS transition on the grid columns.

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/IHUZcvNjPS

Comment: CSS transition animations are complete garbage. Finding a situation where they actually work is a rarity.

Comment: @VahidAmiri They sometimes take testing, but to dismiss them entirely is foolish.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the colmn size by using column sizes provided by Bootstrap. 
For example col-2 to col-1
Then I adjusted the transition to only target the specific type

```
.row [class*='col-'] {
    transition: flex 0.5s ease-in-out, max-width .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been experimenting with this.
Try this out.

```
.container {
    /*transition: flex 0.5s ease-in-out, max-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    */
    transition: flex 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1),
        max-width 0.75s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
```